# Can multiple actions serve the same view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 pages in my application that will be laid out the same. I would like to use the same view for each of them, and pass the content in through the controller. How do I set that up in my controller:

This is my navigation partial looks:

```
@{
    Dictionary<string, string> links = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    links.Add("home", "Index");
    links.Add("neurosurgical", "Neurosurgical");
    links.Add("pain management", "PainManagement");
    links.Add("staff", "Staff");
    links.Add("patient resources", "PatientResources");
    links.Add("contact", "Contact");
}
<nav id="main_menu">
    <ul class="primary_menu">
        @foreach(var link in links)
        {
            <li class="@(link.Value == ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() ? "active" : "")">
                @Html.ActionLink(link.Key, link.Value)
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The similar pages listed above are NeuroSurgical and PainManagement. My controller looks like this right now:

```
namespace ****************.Controllers // Namespace redacted
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

`About` is the view file I have setup to act as the template for both pages. Do I create actions for each page and point them at About.cshtml? How?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Contact()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
    return View("About");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to create actions for each page and have them use the same view.  Something like this:

```
    public ActionResult NeuroSurgical()
    {
        //create your model, etc here
        return View("SharedViewNameHere", model);
    }

    public ActionResult PainManagement()
    {
        //create your model, etc here
        return View("ViewNameHere", model);
    }
```